# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' problem

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to implement a table view that displays books information in every cell. I get this information from the API. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    

    @IBOutlet weak var allBooksTable: UITableView!
    
    var bookList:myList? = nil {
    didSet {
          allBooksTable.reloadData()
       }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.allBooksTable.dataSource = self
        self.allBooksTable.delegate = self

        
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://ipvefa0rg0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/books?lang=fr&term=self")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.setValue(
            "jFXzWHx7SkK6",
            forHTTPHeaderField: "api-key"
        )

        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else if let data = data {
                do {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(myList.self,
                                                               from: data)
                    
                    
                    self.bookList = decodedData
                    print("user: ", decodedData.list[0].imageLinks.thumbnail)

                    print("===================================")
                } catch let DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context) {
                    print(context)
                } catch let DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, context) {
                    print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
                    //print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
                } catch let DecodingError.valueNotFound(value, context) {
                    print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
                    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
                } catch let DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)  {
                    print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
                    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
                } catch {
                    print("error: ", error)
                }
            } else {
                // Handle unexpected error
            }
        }
        
        
        task.resume()
                        
    }
    


}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as! bookTableViewCell
                cell.bookName.text = bookList?.list[indexPath.row].title
        if bookList?.list[indexPath.row].imageLinks.smallThumbnail != nil{
            
            //cell.img.load(url: (bookList?.list[indexPath.row].imageLinks.smallThumbnail)!)
            print((bookList?.list[indexPath.row].imageLinks.smallThumbnail)!)
           cell.img.downloaded(from: (bookList?.list[indexPath.row].imageLinks.smallThumbnail)!)
            
        }

                return cell
    }
    
}


extension UIImageView {
    func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
                self?.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    func downloaded(from link: String, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloaded(from: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it only shows my the first book and then crashes with the following error.

```swift
2020-10-15 23:12:00.953424+1100 MSA[50129:2517792] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043a126 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177f78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreAutoLayout                      0x00007fff58010d41 -[NSISEngine tryToOptimizeReturningMutuallyExclusiveConstraints] + 0
    3   CoreAutoLayout                      0x00007fff58010fcd -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 25
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ac64ad -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _recursiveUpdateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 112
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ac6136 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 827
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ac6a08 __100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 85
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ac6594 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 154
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ac7482 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 393
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ba9ad6 -[UIView _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 275
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24bbda37 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2979
    11  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a3dd87 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 258
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a44239 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 575
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ba8fe9 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 573
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24bb0479 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 84
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff248954d0 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 1300
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2485e8bb -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2942
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2487e6e6 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 237
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24bbd9ce -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2874
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a3dd87 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 258
    20  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a44239 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 575
    21  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a4ff91 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 65
    22  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27990078 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 496
    23  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff279c6e13 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 783
    24  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff279c7616 _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 210
    25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5dcda054 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 551
    26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5dcdc512 _pthread_exit + 70
    27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5dcd9ddd _pthread_wqthread_exit + 77
    28  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5dcd8afc _pthread_wqthread + 481
    29  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5dcd7b77 start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Could you please help me to understand what's going on here? I have looked over for similar threads, but most of the solutions are specific to the question.

Comment: `allBooksTable.reloadData()`, in the `didSet`, it's not in main thread. Read carefully the error: "Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'
". Reloading the TableView, that's UI related, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a UIElement getting update in background thread thats why applications getting crashed so whenever you want to update UI you need to update that UI Element in main thread, and your session data task is running in background thread and there you set the value `bookList` but when `bookList` is set there is an property observer which is reload the tableview in background thread so there is two solutions.

1. inside your api calling functions you need to set the property in main thread like this:-

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.bookList = decodedData
      }
```

2. inside your property observer you need to do like that

```
var bookList:myList? = nil {
    didSet {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              allBooksTable.reloadData()
          }
       }
    }
```

Enjoy:-

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you set `bookList` from a background thread (since `URLSession.dataTask` calls its completion on a background thread) and in the `didSet` of `bookList`, you update the UI. You should dispatch the UI update to the main thread.

```
var bookList:myList? = nil {
    didSet {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              allBooksTable.reloadData()
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `bookList` on main thread like below...

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.bookList = decodedData
  }
```